# Riak does not allow to remove a node

Tags: riak

I added the node to the cluster. Appear on the node there is a problem. Node remains in the status of 'joining'. No data on the cluster.

```
#riak-admin member-status
================================= Membership ==================================
Status     Ring    Pending    Node
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
down        0.0%      --      'riak@172.17.0.145'
joining     0.0%      --      'riak@172.17.0.144'
valid      50.0%      --      'riak@172.17.0.115'
valid      50.0%      --      'riak@172.17.0.143'
```

I'm trying to remove a node from the cluster

```
#riak-admin cluster force-remove 'riak@172.17.0.144'
Failed: 'riak@172.17.0.144' is not a member of the cluster.
```

I'm trying to join the node to the cluster

```
#riak-admin cluster join 'riak@172.17.0.144'
Failed: This node is already a member of a cluster
```

How do I remove a node from the cluster, or to compel it to work normally? Version 1.4.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used your command for removing the node from cluster but one recommended in the documentation : [riak documentation](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/running/nodes/adding-removing/) The command is this `riak-admin cluster leave, riak-admin cluster plan, riak-admin cluster commit` and it worked perfectly. If you don't need to use force-remove to remove node I recommend this one. The same works for joining with `riak-admin cluster join` instead of leave

Answer (score 0):

You can remove node having node name **riak@172.17.0.144**

by just down the node **172.17.0.144** and by commnd force remove **riak-admin force-remove riak@172.16.28.17** from other running node you can remove the node successfully.